# How to encrypt (from http to https) while running server with Uvicorn in python

Tags: python, http, https, fastapi, uvicorn

I am stuck in this issue. We are using LDAP over http server using Fastapi framework that runs with uvicorn. I get to know about certbot but I am not sure how to use it with uvicorn. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have checked this: https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/#https?

Comment: Yes I have checked it. Basically running uvicorn with certificate. I am stuck at generating certificate itself.

Comment: Then it's not a problem with fastapi itself...